# Words in array deleted/popped when sorting through recursion

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, recursion

I am learning Ruby and recursion methods. The problem I am tackling is sorting the words in an array.  My recursion methods sort the array correctly, however, every time I run the array through the method, the last word from the initial array ("word") gets deleted:

```
# Word sorter

def sort(some_array)
  recursive_sort(some_array, [])
end

def recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array)
  if unsorted_array.length <= 0
    return sorted_array
  end

  smallest = unsorted_array.pop
  unsorted = []
  unsorted_array.each do |word|
    if word < smallest
      unsorted << smallest
      smallest = word
    else
      unsorted << word
    end
  end
  sorted_array << smallest
  recursive_sort(unsorted,sorted_array) 
end

words = ['hi', 'welcome', 'bye', 'idk', 'where', 'apples', 'bananas']
sort(words)
puts "#{words}"
sort(words)
puts "#{words}"
sort(words)
puts "#{words}"
```

This is what happens to the "words" array:

```
["hi", "welcome", "bye", "idk", "where", "apples"]
["hi", "welcome", "bye", "idk", "where"]
["hi", "welcome", "bye", "idk"]
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're passing a reference to an object (your var `words`) and you're performing a mutation operation on it (`pop`) which is actually removing the last element of the array each time `recursive_sort` is called.

To fix this, you'll want to use `dup` in order to not mutate your original array as such:

```
def sort(some_array)
  given_array = some_array.dup
  recursive_sort(given_array, [])
end
```

More importantly, to print the output of your function you need to include the method call:

```
words = ['hi', 'welcome', 'bye', 'idk', 'where', 'apples', 'bananas']
puts "#{sort(words)}"
puts "#{sort(words)}"
puts "#{sort(words)}"
puts "#{sort(words)}"

=>
["apples", "bananas", "bye", "hi", "idk", "welcome", "where"]
["apples", "bananas", "bye", "hi", "idk", "welcome", "where"]
["apples", "bananas", "bye", "hi", "idk", "welcome", "where"]
["apples", "bananas", "bye", "hi", "idk", "welcome", "where"]
```

Comment: I personnally would add a ! to `recursive_sort` to notify users that it comes with a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the call to `Array#pop` : it returns the last element of the array and removes it as a side-effect.

Duplicating your unsorted array and use the duplicate in order to to prevent such thing to happen.

def sort(some_array)
  recursive_sort(some_array, [])
end

```
def recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array)
  return sorted_array if unsorted_array.empty?

  source = unsorted_array.dup

  current_word = source.pop
  unsorted = []

  source.each do |word|
    if word < current_word
      unsorted << current_word
      current_word = word
    else
      unsorted << word
    end
  end

  sorted_array << current_word
  recursive_sort(unsorted, sorted_array) 
end
```